# How to prevent duplicate entries in join table using JPA ManyToMany

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, join

I searched on Google and StackOverflow but was unable to find a situation that appears to match mine.

I am using MySQL 5.5 and Java 7 JPA to interface with a database from within Java programs. I have a few tables with a many-to-many relationship and have corresponding join tables defined. I successfully tested adding and removing entries to a join table, but ran into a problem when re-running the "add" test. First, let me provide some of the code for reference:

Member.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @TableGenerator(name = "member_seq_gen", table = "sequence", pkColumnName = "seq_name", valueColumnName = "seq_count", pkColumnValue = "member_seq")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "member_seq_gen")
  private long                        id;

  ... other fields not shown ...

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "j_member_strength", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "member_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "program_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
  private Collection<StrengthProgram> programs;
  ...

  public void register(StrengthProgram program) {
    programs.add(program);
  }

  public void unregister(StrengthProgram program) {
    programs.remove(program);
  }
}
```

StrengthProgram.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "strength_program")
public class StrengthProgram implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @TableGenerator(name = "strength_program_seq_gen", table = "sequence", pkColumnName = "seq_name", valueColumnName = "seq_count", pkColumnValue = "strength_program_seq")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "strength_program_seq_gen")
  private long               id;

  ... other fields not shown ...

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "programs")
  private Collection<Member> members;
  ...
}
```

SQL for the join table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cf531alt`.`j_member_strength` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cf531alt`.`j_member_strength` (
  `member_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `program_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`, `program_id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_member_has_strength_program_member1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`member_id` )
    REFERENCES `cf531alt`.`member` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_member_has_strength_program_strength_program1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`program_id` )
    REFERENCES `cf531alt`.`strength_program` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE INDEX `fk_member_has_strength_program_strength_program1_idx` ON `cf531alt`.`j_member_strength` (`program_id` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_member_has_strength_program_member1_idx` ON `cf531alt`.`j_member_strength` (`member_id` ASC) ;
```

I have logic elsewhere that will "register" or "un-register" a member with a strength program by adding or removing the program object to/from the `programs` collection in the `Member` object.

I was able to register a collection of members with a program and un-register a subset of those members successfully, but when I went to re-run the register test with the original list of members, I got a duplicate entry exception. I understand why this is happening. What I don't know is how to prevent it or handle the situation if/when it arises. Following is an excerpt of the exception:

```
[EL Warning]: 2014-12-29 19:22:25.075--ClientSession(1337625898)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '183-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO j_member_strength (program_id, member_id) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="programs" sql="INSERT INTO j_member_strength (program_id, member_id) VALUES (?, ?)")
...
```

I'm not very familiar with how JPA handles one-to-many or many-to-many relationships in the Java code. I wasn't sure if the relationship would be "created" using the method above until I tried it. I ran the test and then queried the database and to my surprise (and satisfaction) found that entries had been "automatically" made in the join table.

Does anyone have ideas about how to avoid or mitigate the "duplicate entry" problem? If I have not been clear enough or if more code is needed, please let me know.

UPDATE:

Do I need to query the join table to see if an entry exists for the given member/program combination and take appropriate action based upon the result? This would be my first thought, but wasn't sure how much JPA did behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

there is some tips in the code that I think maybe cause a problem:

- you don't need `register(program)` and `unregister(program)` methods, you can directly use `member.programs.add(program)` or `member.programs.remove(program)`.
- in many-to-many association the entities are adding to both side I mean: `program.members.add(member); member.programs.add(program)` after that you can persist the member or program

Comment: Hmm, so I need to "add" to both entity lists to complete the creation of the relationship?